# Using styles or numbered lists to select content between headings

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there a way for vba to find a string of text with a particular style and select until the style is used again? Or is there a way to find a string of text in a numbered list and select until the next number? The heading I want to find and select content under is "SUBMITTALS," but it is not always in the same numerical order in the document, but the style is always the same. Any advice would be appreciated, here is what I have tried:

```
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "SUBMITTALS"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute
Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart

Dim r1 As range
Set r1 = Selection.range
'v = Selection.range.ListFormat.ListValue
'lstring = Selection.range.ListFormat.ListString


Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
    With Selection.Find
    .Text = "SUBMITTALS"
    End With
Dim r5 As range
Set r5 = Selection.Next(wdSection).Next

'If Selection.Find.Execute Then
    'Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart
'Else
    'Selection.WholeStory
    'Selection.Extend
    'Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
'End If

Dim r2 As range
Set r2 = ActiveDocument.range(r1.Start, r5.Start)
r2.Select
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "SUBMITTALS"
    .Style = wdStyleHeading2
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Format = True
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute
  End With
  If .Find.Found = True Then
    Set Rng = .Paragraphs(1).Range
    Set Rng = RngHd.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\HeadingLevel")
    MsgBox Rng.Text
  End If
End With
Set Rng = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```